# Splitting string into a new line in apache-pig

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I want to split the string in a dataset that is joined by a backslash (/) into a new line.

The example datatset is:

```
(David Jones / John Smith)
```

I want the result to be:

```
(David Jones)
(John Smith)
```

The code i have written is:

```
A = FOREACH data GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(name,'/',2));
DUMP A;
```

However the result i'm getting in the terminal is:

```
(David Jones, John Smith)
```

Answer (score 0):

`STRSPLIT` creates a tuple in the same row. Flattening it will collapse it back together.

I suggest trying without the flatten

Answer (score 0):

You should use `TOKENIZE` instead of `STRSPLIT`

Code:

```
A = LOAD 'input.txt' AS (name:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(name,'/'));
DUMP B;
```

Contents of `input.txt`:

```
David Jones/John Smith
```

Output:

```
(David Jones)
(John Smith)
```